# Position child div to the left of parent div?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an image that has a width of 50% and a div with text that is 65% because I want the heading inside the div to overlap the image. But, the problem is that I don't want the other content inside the div to overlap the image - just the heading. I want the text and the button to be next to the image not on top of it.
But I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/tayanderson/pen/EbJZxy

```
.project {
    height: 75vh;
    margin: 15em 0;
    position: relative;

    .project-info {
        z-index: 100;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 65%;
        height: 100%;
        right: 0;
        h2 {
            text-transform: initial;
            color: #eee;
        }
        p {
            font-weight: 300;
            color: #ccc;
            margin: 40px 0;
        }
        .project-desc {
            width: 70%;
            .button {display:inline-block;}
        }
    }

    .project-img {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(50%);
        filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(50%);
        width: 51.3%;
    }

    a {text-decoration:none;
        color: #fff;}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .project-info, .project-img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .project-info {
            left: 0;
            padding: 0 20px;
            .project-desc>*{
                width: 100% !important;
                float: left !important;
            }
            p {display: none;}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are describing. Instead of using the percentages to position the items use position: relative instead and float the image (remember to put it first in the flow).

Check this out:
https://codepen.io/alexplummer/pen/eeoRmN

```
.project-info {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    ...
}
.project-img {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is what I was trying to describe. This works but the only issue was that I also want to center the div vertically. Currently, I'm using flexbox to do that. when I do this, it seems to override that.

Comment: No worries you can still use flexbox, I have updated the codepen so the content is vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that using flexbox.

https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/BmEpeB

```
.article {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.article__image,
.article__text {
  width: 50%;
}

.article__image {
  background: url('http://www.country1067.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/28/2017/07/logoImage_4.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
}

.article__text {
  padding: 12px;
  background: #c3c3c3;
}

.article__text h2 {
  margin-left: -96px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don´t you make the two divs to 50% and give padding to project-info?
You need this attribute for do correctly the padding inside the div

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Here you have the result

https://codepen.io/marcosefrem/pen/BmERmY